# Prevent `nvcc` from mangling function names

Tags: cuda, linker, g++, nvcc

How do I keep `nvcc` (the CUDA c++ compiler) from mangling my function names so that I can call those function from a C program I'm using as an apache module.

Note that I'm linking the objects together using `g++`, which has no knowledge of the `nvcc` names.

Comment: Te lack of an `#ifdef` in the other answer means that the C compiler (that's used to compile the apache module) will complain, because it doesn't understand the `extern` call.  I'm guessing choosing the right compilers to avoid that particular issue could be worked out (certainly, inserting another level of indirection where you use g++ to compile an intermediate cpp file would work), but it's unnecessary.  Also, the other question didn't come up in the search enginer for whatever combo of terms I was using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform `nvcc` that you're referring to the functions external to the universe that `nvcc` will learn about.  We do this by declaring the function as an `extern`.

In your `.h` file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

<rest of your header>

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In your `.cu` file:

```
extern "C" {

<rest of your class definition>

}
```